# Exchange logs with powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to get connection logs from exchange online via powershell.

I have managed to log in to exchange online with powershell, but do not know any cmdlets that would allow me to obtain a list of connections made.  What I am trying to achieve is to see a log entry when someone has logged in to their mailbox and downloaded their emails.  Ideally I am looking for their IP.

get-logonstatistics no longer works (exchange 2013).

Any help at all would be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

For On-Premise Exchange you are looking forMailbox Transport service logs which sit in

*%ExchangeInstallPath%TransportRoles\Logs\Mailbox\Connectivity*

but you have to explicitly enable them first.

This article will get you started

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124500(v=exchg.150).aspx

You can't really do that in O365 without raising a ticket with MS, the only available cmdlets are:

http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/dd575549.aspx

Comment: Could there be a way to get the IP addresses from the domain sign in when they authenticate with the office 365 pro plus domain?

Comment: I doubt it but if you ask MS directly they might have have a way.